# Из двух скриптов сделать один

Tags: jquery

**Необходимо из двух скриптов сделать один.**
Нужно чтобы когда выбиралось connectid=7 и presentId=1 то появляющее окно inbound_from, а если выбиралось connectid=7 и presentId=2 то исчезало inbound_from,  а в остальных случаях например когда connectid=6 и presentId=2 то появлялось inbound_from

1 скрипт - при выборе любого connectid и presentId=2 появляется окно inbound_from, а если выбрать connectid и presentId=1 то исчезает

```
function changepresentId() {
  if($("#presentId" ).val() !=1){
   $('#inboundLetter').fadeIn();
   $('#inbound_from').fadeIn();
   $('#addpetit').fadeOut();
   $('#sel').fadeOut();
  }else{
   $('#inboundLetter').fadeOut();
   $('#inbound_from').fadeOut();
   $('#addpetit').fadeIn();
   $('#sel').fadeIn(); 
  }
  }
```

2 скрипт при выборе connectid=7 и presentId val=1 появляется окно inbound_from а при выборе connectid=7 и presentId val=2 - inbound_from исчезает, а в остальных случаях например connectid=6 и presentId val=1 или val=2 не блокирует inbound_from.

```
function changepresentId() {
  if($("#connectid").val() !=7 || $("#presentId").val() !=2){
   $('#inboundLetter').fadeIn();
   $('#inbound_from').fadeIn();
   $('#addpetit').fadeOut();
   $('#sel').fadeOut();
  }else{
   $('#inboundLetter').fadeOut();
   $('#inbound_from').fadeOut();
   $('#addpetit').fadeIn();
   $('#sel').fadeIn();    
  }

 }
```

Comment: Что именно вызывает сложность? может что то непонятно? или вы хотите готовое решение?

Comment: Да столкнулся с трудностью реализации скрипта с несколькими условиями

Answer (score 0):

```
function changepresentId() {
            if (($("#presentId" ).val() ==1 && ($("#connectid" ).val() !=1 && $("#connectid" ).val() !=7))
                || ($("#presentId" ).val() ==2 && ($("#connectid" ).val() ==1 || $("#connectid" ).val() ==7)))
        {   //Блокировка
                $('#inboundLetter').fadeOut();
                $('#inbound_from').fadeOut();
                $('#addpetit').fadeIn();
                $('#sel').fadeIn(); 
        }else{//Открытие

             $('#inboundLetter').fadeIn();
                $('#inbound_from').fadeIn();
                $('#addpetit').fadeOut();
                $('#sel').fadeOut();
        }
     }
```